# es6 import syntax seems to throw error in chromium 64, but not chrome 62?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, import, chromium, es6-modules

I use firefox, chromium, and chrome as part of my workflow (debian 9).

While experimenting with using the 'import' syntax on non-transpiled static website code, I noticed that I get errors in chromium that I don't get in chrome. That's pretty odd, since I'm running chromium 64 ( 64.0.3282.119 (Developer Build) built on Debian 9.3, running on Debian 9.2 (64-bit)) and chrome  62 (62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)).

When I visit the [well known demo site for es6 modules](https://paulirish.github.io/es-modules-todomvc/), and look at the sources tab, and click on `es6-modules-todomvc/app.js`, chromium underlines the first line `import {updateTodo} from './todo.js'`, starting from the curly brace, and when I hover to get the error, I see "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token {`.

In Chrome? No such error. Everything is fine.

To make things even more odd, while *all* the files in his example show similar errors when I view the sources and hover (including "unexpected token export" for the line `export default Controller` in `controller.js`, etc.)... no errors are logged in the console.

And yet the site seems to work fine in both?

Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I was seeing squiggles in Chrome 65, but then I updated to Chrome 66 and it's happy.

Comment: Hmm, seems it was likely a minor bug that they just fixed, then?

Comment: yeah, I suspect that's it